# Uninitialized Image TreeDoubleBranchTexture from object "Tree"

Tags: texturing, materials

So I made a UV Texture for my tree and called it TreeDoubleBranchTexture. I decided to change it a bit so the texture wouldn't have any shadows anymore.

I did it the same as I always did but it just keeps saying `Uninitialized Image TreeDoubleBranchTexture from object "Tree"` every time I try to bake it.

As a way to remove the shadows I made the surface *Emission* and set the strength to 1.000 for both the wood color and leaf color.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too. It seems I had not actually created an image, just a slot for one. I managed to fumble around until I found *Fill Image With UV Grid*. Then I had an actual image, which I saved, and then it worked.